# How can I remove or change a border/outline on a picture when it is in a gallery page?

Tags: gallery

You can see on this page: http://www.middlegray.net/ceremonies/

the photos have a white box that is automatically applied to the pic. I want to take it off or make it a different color. Where would I look to change that?

Comment: Look at your stylesheets & the border attribute. Sorry to say, but css Qs are off topic.

Comment: not a css kaiser its through his themes function file i bet. It adds a style to the head

Answer (score 1):

add this to your css file

`.attachment-thumbnail{border:medium none!important}`

You could also check the preferences of the gallery to see if there is a way to disable

Can you post your themes functions.php file in an edit on your question. you may be able to filter it out since the theme does a rewrite of the gallery